# How to process business rules when using Dependency Injection and Repository Pattern in Controller?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, repository-pattern

So 99% of all DI examples using the Repository pattern with MVC (or Web API), show something similar to this below in a controller action (left out constructor injection code for `_repository`). The issue is there is the assumption that nothing needs to be processed 1st (like rules) and commencing persistence occurs immediately:

```
public ActionResult Create(Person person)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
      _repository.Add(person);
    }

    return View(person);
}
```

The problem is, what if I need to process *rules* in the domain layer before persisting the `person` object? Obviously I don't do that logic in the Controller, but rather need it in the domain layer. Which option below is better:

**Option 1:** Relegate all persistence details on the repository to be called in the domain / business layer and pull out of the controller. The updated code would look like this:

```
if (ModelState.IsValid)
{
  using (busniessLogic = new MyApp.BusniessLogic(_repository))
  {
       busniessLogic.ProcessRulesAndSavePerson(person);
  }
}
```

The domain layer might have a method like this:

```
public void ProcessRulesAndSavePerson(Person person)
{
   //process some rules...

   if(rules = true)
   {
     //use injected repository to add now that rules have passed
     _repository.Add(person)
   }
}
```

**Option 2:** Keep the same as now in the Controller, but just make a call to process the rules prior to saving on the repository. Updated code is like below:

```
if (ModelState.IsValid)
{
  using (busniessLogic = new MyApp.BusniessLogic())
  {           
       busniessLogic.ProcessRulesAboutPerson(person);
       _repository.Add(person)
  }
}
```

I'm open to other ideas too, but I am leaning toward Option #1. I like to keep the Controller thin and just pass along the injected _repository to the layer requiring it.

Any help on this is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both options will create a dependency on the business logic processor, you always have to be careful when using the `new` keyword because when you try to unit test your method, you almost always will run into problems, and that defeats the purpose of dependency injection.

You are better of creating a service that handles complicated business logic and injecting that into your controller. If most of your logic is complicated, I would just skip passing the repository to the controller all together and just depend on the service to handle everything for me.

Controller:

```
public MyController(IPersonService personService) 
{
    _personService = personService;
}

public ActionResult Create(Person person)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
       _personService.Create(person);
    else
       ......
}
```

PersonService:

```
public PersonService(IPersonRepository repo) 
{
    _repo = repo;
}

public int Create(Person person)
{
    //businesslogic
    return _repo.Add(person);
}
```

Comment: The service layer can just be a .dll correct? Does that mean all of my service/business methods must be defined by an Interface? I think the answer is 'yes', because otherwise I can't inject an instance into the Controller correct?

Comment: @atconway exactly! and you would want an interface anyway, this way you can easily test your controller by injecting a mock into the controller constructor (that's the main reason we are using DI in the first place)

Comment: I like using Service layer; avoided till now but simple enough and read about many times. So here are my layers: UI (MVC), Service Layer, Models/Entities Layer, Repository. So if I use this setup, and the business logic is in my Service Layer, then my Models layer really are just DTOs. In this case am I using an Anemic Domain Model? Should I move the business logic from the service layer to the Models layer?

Comment: There are a lot of back and forth about this subject, I personally prefer smart models up to a point (if my model is interacting with other models, I usually would go with a service. There is no right way, it's whatever makes sense to you. But you are right, you can either go with services, or with smarter domain models!

Comment: Would you say its OK to have *both* a lean Models layer **and** a services layer with business logic? I'm using EF with generated POCO classes, and it does not bother me if the Models layer is mostly DTOs. I guess if I instead lean out the Service layer it becomes somewhat of a proxy just passing calls along without any business logic, correct?

Comment: It's definitely OK, you just have to be consistent. You have to come up with a set of rules and stick with it. You don't have to define these rules up front, but with experience you will come with your own best practices. Just remember to be consistent.

Comment: This was clear as a bell to me. I'll leverage the Service layer as I've seen before to be a conductor for the Repository and Domain Layer keeping it thin. My domain model will remain robust with both data and behavior as I'm actually most comfortable with: http://martinfowler.com/bliki/AnemicDomainModel.html Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 3):

Not necessarily the best way, but this is how I usually do it:

- IService (business logic in your case) is injected into the controller (and not IRepository)
- If ModelState is valid => the Controller will call methods in IService that take model as a parameter(s)
- IRepository is injected to the Service instance, if needed.

This allows me to:
- Be able to unit test controllers providing IService mockups.
- Keep the controller ignorant of the Repository and Data Access layer.